# Is force logging available in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, coreclr, .net-core-logging, asp.net-core-logging

I have ASP.NET Core application. I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` interface with `Serilog` logging provider.
In production environment, the log level is set to `Error`. So anything below `Error` loglevel will not get logged.

Is there `Force` logging available in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, which would log the message regardless of what the loglevel is set?

Basically *I want to log some information (temporarily) without setting LogLevel to Information because that would log all other unrelevant information messages.*

**Update 1**
So i updated my appsettings.json as per the suggestion however that did not work. Note that serilog also has its own loglevel which i have commented out. But Still not working.

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "MyUserService": "Information"
    }   
 },   
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    //"MinimumLevel": "Error",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          //"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
          "connectionString": "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True",
          "tableName": "Logs"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MyApplication"
    }   
}
```

and then in MyUserService

```
public class MyUserService : BaseService, IMyUserService
{

    private readonly ILogger<MyUserService> _logger;

    public MyUserService(MyDBContext dbContext, ILogger<MyUserService> logger)
        : base(dbContext)
    {            
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task DoSomethig()
    {       
       _logger.LogInformation("Log something meaningful here");
    }       
 }
```

and in program.cs

```
     public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .UseUrls("http://*:40006")
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            //removed for brevity
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {         
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

            logging.AddSerilog();         
        })
        .Build();
```

Comment: can you not just log it as an error or fatal etc ? In general the sink uses the min bar to efficiently stop messages being produced in the first instance

Comment: yes, thats my last option if i cant do force logging

Comment: I'm asking why you think you need a force when changing the level of the single message can achieve your result  ?

Comment: because what i am trying to log is not error, its an information ( some metadata) that will help to us make decision. Also we have external `watch` service which sends email to everyone if there is any error logged. i am trying to avoid that

Comment: OK. Can you make a logger for another context and mark that as minimum: info but switch it on ? Or relegate the other infos you dont want to debug ? Bottom line: there is no Force for efficiency, but also consistency reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to configure the log level per log cagtegory.

Once you let yourself inject an `ILogger<MyCategory>` (where `MyCategory` can be any type - a special type just to indicate log categories or just the class you log from), you can configure the log level independent of everything else:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Error",
    "MyCategory": "Information"
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a try and post my answer

Comment: Further to this, I think that (at least in code) the `MinimumLevel.Override(category, level)` may accept a `LoggingLevelSwitch` in place of a level, which you can update at runtime. HTH!

Comment: ok so i got it working by using full class name `MyNameSpace.MyUserService` instead of just a class name `MyUserService`. This link was also helpful https://jonhilton.net/2016/09/21/log-different-levels-in-asp-net-core-app/